# How to specify a control within a datagridcell using style/data triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, contentcontrol

In WPF, I'm trying to create a custom data grid that displays a cell as combobox when there is a databound list of data (a range for data), and a normal textbox if there isn't a limit.  Additionally, i'm using the included validation for IDataErrorInfo and an MVVM pattern.  Most of it works very well, but the devil is in the details.  I'm seeing a problem where the validation on my combobox is not working as I expect it to.

I believe the issue I have is when I define both controls using a data trigger, but I'm not sure why it behaves the way it does.  If I remove the validation on my textbox, the validation on the combobox works beautifully.  When i put the properties back into the textbox to specify validation, the combobox validation no longer works.

Here is my xaml code on how to specify which control to use based on my data trigger:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GlobalVariableEditor.GlobalVariableEditorUserControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:GlobalVariableEditor.ViewModel" 
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GlobalVariableEditor"
        xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="500" Width="auto" Height="auto">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:GlobalVariableEditorViewModel x:Name="_GVEViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="VariablesViewSource" Source="{Binding VariablesData}">
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <Style x:Key="RangeStyleNormal" TargetType="ComboBox">            
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="center"/>       
            <!--<EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></EventSetter>-->
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTextSearchCaseSensitive" Value="True"/>
        </Style>      

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <GroupBox x:Name="grpGVEditor" Header="Global variable editor" FontSize="12">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">           
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--This is for any declarations or headers we may need for initial information (where to load xml file from, etc)-->
                <RowDefinition x:Name="TopRowDefinition" Height="*" MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="50" />
                <RowDefinition x:Name="RevisionRowDefinition" Height="*" MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="50" />
                <!--this is where the data from the xml file should be populated to-->
                <RowDefinition x:Name="DataRowDefinition" Height="*" MinHeight="200"/>
                <!--this is where the buttons should be placed (cancel, apply, etc)-->
                <!--<RowDefinition x:Name="FilterRowDefinition" Height="*" MinHeight ="25" MaxHeight="30"/>-->
                <RowDefinition x:Name="ButtonRowDefinition" Height="*" MinHeight ="30" MaxHeight="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Label Height="30" Width="110" Content="XML file location: " BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="3,0,3,0"/>
                <Label x:Name="lblCustomXMLFilePath" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="350" Content="{Binding FilePath}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,3,0" ToolTip="{Binding FilePath}" Background="Gray"/>
                <!--<Button x:Name="btnLoad" Height="30" Width="50" Content="Load" Margin="0,5,5,5" Click="btnLoad_Click" Visibility="Hidden"/>-->
                <Button Height="30" Width="50" Content="Revert" Margin="0,0,3,0" ToolTip="Revert to TP values" Visibility="Hidden"/>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Label Name="lblRevID" Height="30" Width="110" Content="File Revision ID: " BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="3,0,3,0"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtRevID" Padding="3" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,3,0" Text="{Binding FileVersion}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Gray">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileVersion}" Value="-1">
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Salmon" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.ToolTip" Value="Invalid revision number.  Settings file is in read-only mode." />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileVersion}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Salmon" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.ToolTip" Value="Invalid revision number.  Settings file is in read-only mode." />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbDummy" Visibility="Hidden"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <DataGrid x:Name="PropertyGrid" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"  RowHeaderWidth="0" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredGridEntries}" Margin="3,0,0,0">

                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                            </Style.Resources>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding HasWriteAccess}" ></Setter>

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                </Trigger>

                                <MultiDataTrigger >
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_cboShowAll}" Value="False"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Name="CenterContent" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Column.(ToolTipService.ToolTip), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                        <Image x:Name="rowHeaderImage"
                       x:Key="rowHeaderTemplate"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Width="64"                       
                       Margin="1,0">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/access.ico"/>
                                        </DataTrigger >
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/no_access.jpg"/>
                                        </DataTrigger >                                        
                                    </Style.Triggers>


                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>

                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
                        <BindingGroup/>
                    </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <!--This is the Name column-->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Global variable name/ID" MinWidth ="200" Width="2*">

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="{Binding Name}"/>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <!--This is the Site column-->
                        <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Site" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Site" Width="1*" MaxWidth ="30" IsReadOnly="False" Visibility="Hidden">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Site, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Background="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>-->

                        <!--This is the Slot column-->
                        <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Slot" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Slot" Width="1*" MaxWidth ="30" IsReadOnly="False" Visibility="Hidden">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Slot, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Background="Transparent"/>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>-->

                        <!--This is the High Limit column-->
                        <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="High Limit" ToolTipService.ToolTip="High limit" MaxWidth="125" Width="1*" Visibility="Hidden">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding HiLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Background="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>-->

                        <!--This is the Low Limit column-->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" MinWidth="200" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Global variable programmed value" Width="3*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>                          

                                    <!--By default, allow the user to free edit the combobox.  
                                        This allows backwards compatibility with existing TP settings-->

                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                        <ContentControl.Style>

                                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">

                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasRange}" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <ComboBox                                                                                                                                            
                                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Range, Mode=OneWay}"                                                                      
                                                                      MinWidth="50"                                                                      
                                                                      Text="{Binding ProgrammedValue,                                                                        
                                                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                                                                       ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                                                       NotifyOnValidationError=True}"                                                                      
                                                                      Style="{StaticResource RangeStyleNormal}"
                                                                      Width="auto" >

                                                                    </ComboBox>



                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>

                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasRange}" Value="false">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <TextBox 
                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                               
                                                                        Background="Transparent" 
                                                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                                                        MinWidth="50"                                                                        
                                                                        Text="{Binding ProgrammedValue, Mode=TwoWay,                                                                        
                                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                                                                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                                                        NotifyOnValidationError=True
                                                                        }"                                                                        
                                                                        TextAlignment="Center"
                                                                        Width="Auto">
                                                                    </TextBox>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>

                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ContentControl.Style>
                                    </ContentControl>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <!--This is the Low Limit column-->
                        <!--<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Low Limit" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Lower limit" Width="1*" MaxWidth="125" Visibility="Hidden">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LowLimit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Background="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>-->

                        <!--This is the Fleet column-->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fleet Variable" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Global variable scope" MinWidth ="75" Width="1*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                                </Style>

                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding IsFleet}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="{Binding IsFleet}"/>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is fleet" Width="1*" MinWidth="50"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Variable of fleet scope" Binding="{Binding IsFleet}" IsReadOnly="True">

                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>-->
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DockPanel>
            <!--These are the buttons at the bottom of the control-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2" Width="auto">
                    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40" Margin="5,2,3,0">Filter:</Label>
                    <TextBox x:Name="_tboFilter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="200" MaxLength="40" MaxLines="1" MinLines="1" AcceptsTab="True" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <CheckBox Name="_cboShowAll" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" IsChecked="False" Margin="15,7,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Show all" />
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Height="40" Width="auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2">
                    <Button x:Name="btnTestError" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="25" Width="60" Content="TestError" ToolTip="Fire error events for logging" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding TestErrorButtonCommand}" Visibility="{Binding EnableQADebuggingTools}" />
                    <!--<Button x:Name="btnApply" Height="25" Width="50" Content="Apply" ToolTip="Apply changes" Margin="0,3,3,0" Click="btnApply_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding HasDataChanged}" />-->
                    <Button x:Name="btnApply" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Width="50" Content="Apply" ToolTip="Apply changes" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding ApplyChangesButtonCommand}" >
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <!-- Button enabled if the following conditions is met:  HasDataChanged is true -->
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding HasDataChanged}" Value="True"/>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding HasWriteAccess}" Value="True"/>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>

                    <!--<Button x:Name="btnCancel" Height="25" Width="50" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,3,3,0" ToolTip="Revert to TP values" Click="btnCancel_Click" Command="{Binding CancelButtonCommand}"/>-->
                    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Width="50" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,0,3,0" ToolTip="Revert to TP values" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

</UserControl>
```

IDataErrorInfo is implemented thusly:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;

        try
        {
            if (columnName == "ProgrammedValue")
            {
                //Validation routine: data can not be empty field.

                if (this.HasRange)
                {
                    // This is a combobox
                    if (ProgrammedValue == null)
                    {
                        result = "Field must have selection";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Range != null && !Range.Contains(ProgrammedValue) )
                        {
                            result = "Field must have selection";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is a text box:
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProgrammedValue))
                    {
                        result = "Field can not be empty.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Eat the exception.. really should never get here, but if there is an exception
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In my model, the bound properties are defined:

```
public string ProgrammedValue
{
    get
    {
        return _programmedValue;
    }

    set
    {
        _programmedValue = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ProgrammedLimit");
    }
}


public List<string> Range
{
    get
    {
        return _range;
    }

    set
    {
        _range = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Range");
    }
}

public bool HasRange
{
    get
    {
        return _hasRange;
    }

    set
    {
        _hasRange = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("HasRange");
    }
}
```

RangeStyleNormal definition:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="RangeStyleNormal" TargetType="ComboBox">            
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="center"/>       
            <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></EventSetter>
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTextSearchCaseSensitive" Value="True"/>
        </Style>      

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

As previously stated, when I remove ValidatesOnDataErrors and NotifyOnValidationError from the textbox properties, the combobox works like a charm.  I know that the validation routine I have specified works correctly.  I'm hoping someone here can see some obvious coding error(s) I've made and explain what I did wrong and how to correct it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example, including a minimal viewmodel with your IDataErrorInfo implementation, so we can test your code? Can you also describe exactly how the validation is not "working as expected"? What do you expect, and what's it doing instead?

Comment: Is your combobox editable? Is that why you are using Text property instead of SelectedItem?

Comment: The combobox is not editable because the user is to choose a range from the selection.  If there is no range specified (in this case bound for the combobox list selection) then it should use a default textbox control.  In either case, the validation is just to make sure there are no empty fields.

Comment: Ed, what is currently happening is that for any field i have that is a combobox, the validation routine for the textbox is being applied, or so it seems.  I can see this when I remove the  "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, abd NotiifyOnValidationError=True"properties from the combobox definition because the validation still occurs and I get red error boxes in the datacell.  Let me see if I can get more code in there

Comment: It's as if both combobox and textbox controls are applied to the datacell is what the symptom feels like.

Comment: I have a mockup of the tool that I'm working on that has the issue, is it possible to attach zip files with projects... or does that need to be hosted elsewhere?

Comment: @shivan128   `ProgrammedValue` calls `RaisePropertyChanged("ProgrammedLimit");` -- I don't know (yet) if that's an issue with this validation thing, but it's definitely a bug.

Comment: @shivan128 I've tested your code (with the above bug) and validation works fine. I put a breakpoint in `this[string columnName]` and at runtime, `this` is always the correct row object: All the properties of `this` are correct for the row I just edited, including `HasRange`, so the correct validation is applied. Are you seeing something different in the debugger when you put a breakpoint there? A couple more questions for you: A) You don't say what class `this[string columnName]` is a member of. Same class as `HasRange` etc.? B) What's in `RangeStyleNormal`?

Comment: Ed, thanks for the help so far:  A)  the class i define this[string columnName] is the same class where my properties are defined in the model:  delcaration as follows:  public class PropertyGridRowDataObject : GlobalVariableEditorModelBase, IDataErrorInfo    B)  I added my style to the code snippets above.  At some point, i renamed ProgrammedLimit to ProgrammedValue... unfortunately this did not update the xaml file references.  I've made that change and retry it

Comment: @shivan128 Still works with the style. **What's in ComboBox_SelectionChanged? How are you populating the DataGrid?** That ProgrammedValue rename thing is why you never pass a property name as a string literal to `RaisePropertyChanged`. Always use `CallerMemberName`, so that bug can't happen.

Comment: SelectionChanged only toggles a bit that I use to detect a change later for saving.  It doesnt affect any other area with respect to this particular issue.  And thanks for the CallerMemberName tip!  I retried this and it looks like the issue is still there.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't in any of the code you posted here. I don't have time for guessing, but it would only take a few minutes to find the problem if I had a complete example that reproduces the error.

Comment: When I hook this up to my debugger, this[string columnName] never hits my breakpoint after I make a selection from the pulldown options... where as in my mockup code, it does.   Maybe this is a clue as to what is happening.  I'll see if i can figure out the difference between the mockup and the actual code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i have included all of the xaml code above.

Comment: @shivan128 I asked you for a complete example that reproduces the problem. If you'd provided it, you'd have had your answer. Well, I wish you luck figuring this out.